# Linker in XCode requires full path to the library

Tags: xcode, static-linking, library-path

I need to configure conditional linking in XCode for iPad application.
(I have separate libs for debug/release, armv7/i386). Conditioning on architecture/configuration works fine, however Linker requires full pathes to the libraries even if I add pathes required to "Library search pathes".

So I must add "/full/path/my.lib" to "Other linking flags" instead of just "my.lib"

It's a little annoying when there are a lot of libs. Any thoughts what I'm missing here?

Comment: Library search path is working fine for my project and I am not using the full path in my "Other Linker Flags". Are you sure that your setting it correctly for al the build configurations e.g. debug/release?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, because to start working I just add path from Library search to lib name.

Comment: Try adding the library using <Target Name>Build Phases->Link Binary With Libraries->"+"->Add Other..."